# How to get log probabilities in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to convert a pytorch script to tensorflow and I need to get log probabilities from a categorical distribution. But the tensorflow calculated log probabilities is different from pytorch's log prob even after using same seed. This is what I have done so far

```
import torch 
from torch.distributions import Categorical
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

torch.manual_seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(1)

probs =[0.4,0.6]
m = Categorical(torch.tensor(probs))
action = m.sample()

n = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs)
print("pytorch",m.log_prob(action))
print("Tensorflow", tf.math.log(n.prob(action.item())))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs)
```

takes logs as the default argument. They are being normalized and resulting probabilities of built distribution are [.45, .55].

You need to build tfp distribution as:

```
 tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=probs)
```